# allow_destroy in a form_for helper - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Can I use the 'magic' `_destroy` attribute that works for [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#M002132) for a regular `form_for` helper?

I have a file that I'm uploading via Paperclip and I'd like to have the option to delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes indeed - here's a contrived example in Haml.

```
- form_for @obj, :url => obj_path, :method => :put do |f|
  - f.fields_for :sub, f.object.sub do |sub_form|
    - unless sub_form.object.new_record?
      %span.label= sub_form.label '_delete', 'Remove File'
      %span.input= sub_form.check_box '_delete'
```

And in the model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub, :allow_destroy => true
```

**EDIT - NEW ANSWER:** Yes, you can, but it's less "magical". You need to define your own virtual attribute on the model to be checked prior to the save. Here's an (untested) example that *does not* use nested attributes:

```
- form_for @obj do |f|
  - unless f.object.new_record?
    %span.label= f.label 'delete_file', 'Remove File'
    %span.input= f.check_box 'delete_file'
```

And in the model:

```
  attr_accessor :delete_file  # this is the "virtual attribute" that gets set by the checkbox
  before_update :remove_file
  def remove_file
    self.file = nil if self.delete_file == '1'
  end
```

See [Railscasts #167](http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes) for a more detailed explanation of virtual attributes.

Comment: I meant without nested attributes - `for a regular form_for helper?`

Comment: Gotcha - I updated my answer with an example not using nested attributes.

Comment: incredible! almost 5 years later this still works like a charm